# If I send multiple packets over Networkstream, will they all arrive in the same order?

Tags: c#, networkstream

Currently, I am coding a client/server application that uses `TcpListener`/`TcpClient`.  I've seen similar questions with similar answers, but I have seen conflicting answers and want to clarify with a question dealing directly with this inquiry.  So, if I write bytes to the client's underlying `NetworkStream`, will the byte "groups" (i.e. If I call `NetworkStream.write()` twice client-side) arrive at the server in the same order that the client wrote them?  For example, if I do:

```
stream.write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hi"));
stream.write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("goodbye"));
```

Will `stream.read()` always get the byte array that reads "hi" first, or is there some sort of chance that "goodbye" would be read first?  (I am defining each message's length in the message header, so knowing how long each message is isn't an issue.)

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol that guarantees delivery in order.

Comment: The order is kept, the grouping isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with NetworkStream but TCP delivers these messages in the original order sent - many systems depend strongly on this.

Comment: A `NetworkStream` is just used to handle streaming protocols. It depends on the underlying protocol (in this case TCP), so nothing really changes. :)